# Angular 2 lazily loaded routes that contain aux router outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm having an issue with my routing that I'd need a little help with.  Originally I had all my routing in a single `app.routing.ts` file.  I'm currently refactoring my routes into a files to accompany their corresponding feature modules to be lazily loaded.  One lazily loaded feature module utilizes a secondary aux router outlet.  Here is my code....

### original : app.routing.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'settings',
        component: SettingsComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: '/settings/(settings:user)',
            pathMatch: 'full'
          },
          {
            path: 'user',
            component: SettingsUserComponent,
            outlet: 'settings'
          }
        ]
    }
]
```

#### new: app.routing.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  ...
  {
      path: 'settings',
      loadChildren: '@app/settings/settings.module#SettingsModule'
  }
  ...
]
```

#### settings.routing.ts

```
export const SETTINGS_ROUTES = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/settings/(settings:user)',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'user',
        component: SettingsUserComponent,
        outlet: 'settings'
    }
]
```

So the issue is that originally my `settings` path would load the `SettingsComponent` that contains the `settings` outlet.  The empty child path would then redirect to `/settings/(settings:user)` and load the `SettingsUserComponent` in the `settings` aux router outlet.

Now that I've refactored, there is no `SettingsComponent` being loaded so an error occurs saying that there is not a `settings` outlet.

From the documentation, it states that I'm not able to use `component` attribute with `loadChildren`.  I can't use `component` with `redirectTo` in the `SETTINGS_ROUTES` either.  I've tried wrapping my settings routes in another empty path like below but didn't seem to solve the problem.

#### settings.routing.ts

```
export const SETTINGS_ROUTES = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: 'SettingsComponent',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/settings/(settings:user)',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'user',
                component: SettingsUserComponent,
                outlet: 'settings'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How do I go about loading my `SettingsComponent` that contains the `settings` outlet for the child routes.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

#### Update

> https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10981#issuecomment-301787482

There is an issue for this since Aug 2016.  Some have been able to create workarounds with Angular4.  I've tried them but don't seem to work properly with Angular2.

If anyone has a successful workaround for Angular2, I'd appreciate if you'd post them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update to provide a solution to this problem.  After reading through the issue reported on github, Keith Gillette's solutions works after I fiddled around with it a bit.

> https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10981#issuecomment-301787482

---

#### Solution:

The way that I constructed my routes are as follows:

1. Initial empty path with no component declared.
2. You will then declare child routes on this empty path with all your sub paths.
3. The sub paths declare the path and the base component that contains your aux router outlet.  In my case the `SettingsComponent` contains my `settings` router outlet.
4. Each sub path will then declare another set of children containing an empty path with the component to be loaded in the aux router outlet.

Below is an example of my routes that are working.

#### app.routing.ts (stays the same)

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'schedule',
    loadChildren: '@app/schedule/schedule.module#ScheduleModule'
  }
];
```

#### settings.routing.ts

```
export const SETTINGS_ROUTES = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'schedule',
        component: SettingsComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: SettingsScheduleComponent,
            outlet: 'settings'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'user',
        component: SettingsComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: SettingsUserComponent,
            outlet: 'settings'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

---

#### Note:

One thing to note is that the paths no longer follow the aux router path pattern.

#### Aux Route Path

```
<a [routerLink]="['/settings', { outlets: { settings: 'user'} }]">
  User
</a>
```

#### New Routing Paths

```
<a [routerLink]="['/settings/user']">
  User
</a>
```

---

#### Conclusion

This solutions works for my routing.  I did not test it for multiple nested child routes though.  Reading some of the comments on the above linked github issue, some are reporting that child routes where you declare the component to be loaded in the aux router outlet only seem to work with empty paths.  I did not test this.  You may need to continue nesting empty router paths with aux routers to workaround this.  Hope this helps.