# Can I put multiple route outlets or how I achieve multiple routes?

Tags: routes, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I would like to achieve multiple route outlets. The thing I want to implement is that there are two panels (left and right panel), specifically in the left panel, there are multiple links, such as basic product search and tree product search. So, when users click basic search, the correponding basic search panel would be displayed at the left panel while when users click tree search, the tree search panel would be shown at the left panel. I know that this can be achieved using routerLink. However, I would like to  have one more route outlets at the right panel. So, at the left panel, the resultant products after searching would be displayed in the tabular format, and users can click the product they want at that table, the product detail will be presented at the right panel. However, there are more contents I want to show at the right panel, in other words, if users click some links at the product detail, the new content should be provided at the right panel. I would like to implement this, how am I able to achieve this? Thank you so much!!

Comment: you can use a names aux router outlet, https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/aux-routes.html

Comment: Yes, I found this before posting this question, is this actually continuously supported? There was no explanation about this in angular.io. So, I has been curious about whether using this is safe enough or not. :)

Comment: As far as I'm aware it is still supported in Angular 4.  It doesn't seem to be a very popular feature for some reason.  There are some bugs in Angular 2 like lazy loading modules with aux routing doesn't work as expected (there are work arounds).  There has been an issue ticket open since Aug 2016 for that and hasn't been fixed.  Not sure if that is still the case for Angular 4.  Just sharing what I've notices since I've used it.

Comment: I achieve this using auxiliary outlet-router, but the URL becomes complicated like 'http://localhost:4200/#/search;term=(aux:id/1106886323/products)'. If I look at the gmail, even there is new window when composing a new mail, the url still is shown as 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=new' without any indication of second outlet-router, if you guys have some idea about it, could you please let me know about it?

Comment: if you want to simplify  your aux routes you have to do some route nesting.  I've done this with my projects and have done a couple answers on here explaining how.  check out these posts. 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511536/angular-4-router-why-path1-outlet-namepath2-is-a-thing/45513109#45513109   &&  2.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394728/angular-2-lazily-loaded-routes-that-contain-aux-router-outlet/45400430#45400430

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it seems complicate, after going thorough and if there is something to ask you, I will post again.